# Collapsed Nav Button not working on mobile for twitter bootstrap design

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

Having an issue where the collapsible nav menu button does not work at all on mobile browsers. It works perfectly fine in on desktop and have a sneaking suspicion it has to do with the parallax script that my client installed. Here is the page:

```
http://217.199.187.67/p11demo.com/
```

Comment: Switched the JS to bootstrap 2 as the html hints at that version being used.

Answer (score 0):

You are using the JS of bootstrap 3 and the responsive css of bootstrap 2

Css for Bs2

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/p11demo.com/templates/mikemc/css/bootstrap-responsive.css" type="text/css" media="all">
```

Js for Bs3

```
  <script src="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Comment: switched the js to BS2 and still no go

Comment: You have serius CSS problems, try adding your custom css before the responsive...

Comment: tried what you stated and didnt work either. guessing this html/css needs a serious rewrite, wouldn't you agree?

Comment: No doubt about it... sorry man I try it, but the code is really messy

Comment: there are so many CSS rules breaking the Bootstrap responsivesness

Comment: Yeah I assumed as much... afraid that I wont be able to fix this issue. Probably isn't worth the $50 to do this gig XD